# How to click the "month" button on a website with the help of selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, screen-scraping

I need to be able to click on a certain button on a website. It is on the Hungarian energy market. I am using selenium to automate a few steps. I get a cookies popup which I successfully click but then I need to be able to click on the "Month" button. I inspected it and found the xpath but still when I run it in Jupyter nothing happens after the "I accept" is clicked on the cookies tab. I would need to extract the information on the futures for the next month. This is the site: https://hudex.hu/en/market-data/power/daily-data#short-term

Here is my code so far:

```
> from selenium import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.common.by
> import By import pandas as pd from selenium.webdriver.support.ui
> import WebDriverWait from selenium.webdriver.support import
> expected_conditions as EC from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service import time from
> selenium import webdriver
> 
> driver =
> webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/diyorda02/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe")
> driver.get("https://hudex.hu/en/market-data/power/daily-data")
> 
> coockies_click = driver.find_element("xpath", '//button[@class="button
> primary"]["Accept"]').click()
> 
> 
> wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
> 
> month_click = driver.find_element("xpath", '//a[@class="button
> text-nowrap"]["Month"]').click()
```

Comment: after accepting the cookies, refresh the page and click on it.

Comment: Tried with driver.refresh() but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
month = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@class,"button") and @data-type="month"]')
month.click()
```

I've modified the `xpath` slightly (`a` tag that contains `button` in the `class` and the `data-type` attribute is `month`) and it seems to be working fine for me.
I've also added the `By` class to utilise it's locator strategy. It provides a set of locator strategies for selecting web elements on a page. See the following link

[Locating elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)